# How to replicate the file/directory permissions with P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, security, pinvoke, file-permissions

I'm searching for the solution for hours, but the documentation being sparse, I'm unable to find what I need.

If I have a file or a directory, how can I, in C# with P/Invoke, duplicate the permissions (ie. the owner and SIDs with their permissions) from one file to another or from one directory to another, assuming that those files and directories are either on the same machine or the network controlled by the same Active Directory server?

Comment: why do you need pinvoke? does `System.IO.File.SetAccessControl("dest_file", System.IO.File.GetAccessControl("src_file"));` not do what you want?

Comment: `System.IO.File` methods are limited to 259 characters paths, so they cannot be used in my specific case which has to deal with very long paths.

Comment: can't you switch on long paths with \\?\

Comment: While I haven't tried and can't say for sure, it seems from reading [this help doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that .NET doesn't support long paths at all. It looks like it requires both Win32 calls and the long path specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and
[SetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace PermissionsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source = "C:\\source.txt";
            string dest = "C:\\dest.txt";

            string result = CopyPermissions(source, dest);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) { Console.WriteLine(result); }
            else { Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS"); }
        }

        public static string CopyPermissions(string source_file, string dest_file)
        {
            string errmsg = string.Empty;
            IntPtr sidOwner = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr sidOwnerDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr sidGroup = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr sidGroupDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr dacl = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr daclDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr sacl = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                int result = GetNamedSecurityInfo(source_file, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl, out sidOwner, out sidGroup, out dacl, out sacl, out daclDescriptor);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(result);
                    errmsg = "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                    return errmsg;
                }
                result = GetNamedSecurityInfo(source_file, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, SecurityInfos.Owner, out sidOwner, out sidGroup, out dacl, out sacl, out sidGroupDescriptor);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(result);
                    errmsg = "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                    return errmsg;
                }

                result = GetNamedSecurityInfo(source_file, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, SecurityInfos.Group, out sidOwner, out sidGroup, out dacl, out sacl, out sidGroupDescriptor);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(result);
                    errmsg = "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                    return errmsg;
                }

                SecurityInfos info = SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl | SecurityInfos.Group | SecurityInfos.Owner;
                result = SetNamedSecurityInfo(dest_file, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, info, sidOwner, sidGroup, dacl, sacl);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(result);
                    errmsg = "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                    return errmsg;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sidOwnerDescriptor != IntPtr.Zero && LocalFree(sidOwnerDescriptor) != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(err);
                    errmsg += "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                }
                if (sidGroupDescriptor != IntPtr.Zero && LocalFree(sidGroupDescriptor) != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(err);
                    errmsg += "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                }
                if (daclDescriptor != IntPtr.Zero && LocalFree(daclDescriptor) != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(err);
                    errmsg += "ERROR: " + e.Message;
                }
            }

            return errmsg;
        }

        public enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
        {
            SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE = 0,
            SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            SE_SERVICE,
            SE_PRINTER,
            SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
            SE_LMSHARE,
            SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
            SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
            SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
            SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
            SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetNamedSecurityInfoW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetNamedSecurityInfo(string objectName, SE_OBJECT_TYPE objectType,
            System.Security.AccessControl.SecurityInfos securityInfo, out IntPtr sidOwner,
            out IntPtr sidGroup, out IntPtr dacl, out IntPtr sacl, out IntPtr securityDescriptor);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetNamedSecurityInfoW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int SetNamedSecurityInfo(string objectName, SE_OBJECT_TYPE objectType,
            System.Security.AccessControl.SecurityInfos securityInfo, IntPtr sidOwner,
            IntPtr sidGroup, IntPtr dacl, IntPtr sacl);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LocalFree", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);
    }
}
```